# Is it possible to have two models $M$, $N$ and for each one an elementary embedding to the other one, but $M$, $N$ are not isomorphic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Is it possible to have two models $M$ and $N$ of a theory $T$, an elementary embedding $f$ from $M$ to $N$, and also an elementary embedding $g$ from $N$ to $M$, but such that $M$ and $N$ are not isomorphic?

I myself think the answer is no, but I don't have any good reasons. I'm looking for an example.

Comment: I'm not sure of the details, but perhaps one could take $M=F_2$ the free group on two generators, $N=F_\infty$ the free group on countably-many generators. It is known that they are elementarily-equivalent, that they embed into each other, and are not isomorphic. However, I'm not sure how to show that they embed elementarily into one another (or if the standard embeddings are elementary).

Comment: What about $M=\langle(0,1)\cup(1,2),\lt\rangle$ and $N=\langle(0,1),\lt\rangle$? They are not isomorphic, and I guess (but I'm not a logician) that each is elementarily embeddable in the other. For a possible example with countable models, what if $M$ and $N$ are ordered sets of type $(\omega^*+\omega)\eta$ and $(\omega^*+\omega)(1+\eta)$ respectively, where $\omega^*$ is the order type of the negative integers and $\eta$ is the order type of the rational numbers?

Comment: I don't understand the vote to close as "unclear" - this question is perfectly clear.

Comment: @Hayden Sela showed that if $m,n\geq 2$ and $f\colon F_m\to F_n$ embeds $F_m$ as a free factor of $F_n$, then $f$ is elementary, and Perin showed the converse in her thesis. So the standard embedding $F_2\to F_\infty$ is elementary, but I don't believe $F_\infty$ elementarily embeds in $F_2$ (unless $F_\infty$ embeds as a free factor of $F_2$ - I don't think that should be possible, but I don't know enough about free groups to easily see that it doesn't happen). In any case, the model theory of free groups is extremely complicated, so it probably isn't the best source of simple examples!

Comment: [John Goodrick](https://matematicas.uniandes.edu.co/~goodrick/) studied variants of this question, under the name *Schröder-Bernstein (SB) property*, in his PhD thesis and two follow-up papers with Chris Laskowski (see publications 1, 5, and 9 on the linked page). [Here](https://ffbandf.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/when-are-bi-embeddable-models-isomorphic/) is a blog post by John summarizing the results.

Comment: @bof You should add that as an answer - a countable example is valuable, since uncountable examples do *not* automatically "truncate" to yield countable counterexamples (and you're right that you get elementary embeddings in both directions - this can be proved e.g. via EF-games or quantifier elimination in an expansion-by-definitions).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One simple source of examples is the theory of dense linear orders.  This theory has quantifier elimination, so any embedding is elementary.  So, for instance, $M=\mathbb{R}$ and $N=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ each elementarily embed in the other (the embedding $N\to M$ is obvious and $M$ embeds in $N$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is order-isomorphic to any open interval in $\mathbb{R}$).  However, they are not isomorphic, since $\mathbb{R}$ is Dedekind-complete and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is not.

Answer (score 5):

In a comment, bof has given a countable counterexample, and Eric's answer gives an example of size continuum. Here's an example which is "all about" cardinality: there is no interesting model-theoretic structure at all, a model is characterized entirely by a multiset of cardinals, and it all comes down to making a pair of sequences of cardinals which "dovetail."

Consider the language consisting of a single binary relation $E$. Let's look at two different models which consist of infinitely many $E$-equivalence classes.

- In $\mathcal{A}$, we have one $E$-class of cardinality $\aleph_{2n}$ for each $n\in\omega$.
- In $\mathcal{B}$, we have one $E$-class of cardinality $\aleph_{2n+1}$ for each $n\in\omega$.

The theory of these structures, as in Eric's example, has quantifier elimination, so all embeddings are elementary.

Comment: Note that one way in which bof's example improves over both Eric's and mine is that ours dissolve after [forcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)): if we collapse cardinalities to make our structures countable, they become isomorphic. By contrast, non-isomorphism of *countable* structures is [set-theoretically absolute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness): if $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ are countable and $\mathcal{A}\not\cong\mathcal{B}$, then $V[G]\models\mathcal{A}\not\cong\mathcal{B}$ for every generic extension of the universe $V[G]$.

Comment: There are a number of papers which explore the idea of isomorphism in forcing extensions from various perspectives in logic. For only a few examples, from pure model theory we have "Forcing isomorphism" by Baldwin/Laskowski/Shelah and "Forcing a countable structure to belong to the ground model" by Kaplan/Shelah; from the descriptive set theoretic side of model theory we have "Borel Complexity and Potential Canonical Scott Sentences" by Laskowski/Rast/Ulrich; and I've been involved in a couple papers with a computability-theoretic perspective.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example with *countable* models, in fact, countable ordered sets. (By *ordered set* and *order type* I mean *linearly* ordered set and *linear* order type.)

**Lemma 1.** Let $\varphi,\psi$ be order types. If $(\omega^*+\omega)\varphi=(\omega^*+\omega)\psi,$ then $\varphi=\psi.$

**Lemma 2.** Let $M,N$ be ordered sets with order types $\operatorname{tp}M=(\omega^*+\omega)\varphi,\ \operatorname{tp}N=(\omega^*+\omega)\psi.$
If $\varphi\le\psi,$ then $M$ is elementarily embeddable in $N.$

Lemma 1 is more or less obvious. For Lemma 2, the method of [Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game) may be used to show that the natural embedding is elementary.

Now all we have to do is find countable order types $\varphi,\psi$ such that $\varphi\le\psi\le\varphi$ while $\varphi\ne\psi.$ For this we can take $\varphi=\eta$ and $\psi=1+\eta$ where $\eta$ is the order type of the rational numbers; or, if scattered orderings are preferred, $\varphi=\omega^*\omega$ and $\psi=1+\omega^*\omega$ will do.